# How to replace all items meeting a given criteria in a list

Tags: netlogo

I've been using this post ([how to do replacing-item in use nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182872/how-to-do-replacing-item-in-use-nested-list)) as a guide to work out how to replace items in a list, that meet a given criteria.

Specifically, I want to replace all zeros in a list with the value = 0.5. However, the code I've come up with only seems to replace the first zero in the list and I can't seem to work out why.

This is my code:

```
to-report A-new-list-without-zeros [old new the-list]
 let A-index-list n-values length the-list [?]
 ( foreach A-index-list the-list
   [ if ?2 = old  
      [ report replace-item ?1 the-list new ]
   ])
 report the-list
end
```

And this is what happens:

```
observer> show A-new-list-without-zeros 0 0.5 [0 1 0 5 5 0]
observer: [0.5 1 0 5 5 0]
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you use `report`, it exits the procedure and reports the output at that point. The quick fix using your code is to change the `report` line in your if statement so that it replaces the item at the current index:

```
to-report A-new-list-without-zeros [old new the-list]
 let A-index-list n-values length the-list [?]
 ( foreach A-index-list the-list
   [ if ?2 = old  
      [ set the-list replace-item ? the-list new ]
   ])
 report the-list
end

observer> print A-new-list-without-zeros  0 0.5 [ 0 1 0 5 5 0 ] 
[0.5 1 0.5 5 5 0.5]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Luke C! That works perfectly! Just curious though, why did the nested `report` command work in the post I used as a guide? Is it because that example was focused only on the first item or because it dealt with nested lists?

Comment: No worries! If you're talking about the second part of @Seth Tisue's answer in your link, you'll notice that he has nested a reporter inside of a reporter. So in that case his `report-first` would either report the list with replacement **or** without replacement of the first item- but it wouldn't carry on. Once `report` is called, that procedure is done. The trick is that `replace-first` was nested within `replace-firsts`, so `replace-firsts` was iterating over the umbrella list and using `replace-first` to evaluate the sublists. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah I see... think I get it now. Thanks for explaining and helping me out again! :)

Comment: Right on. Anytime, happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

This task is more easily accomplished with `map` than `foreach`.

NetLogo 6 syntax:

```
to-report A-new-list-without-zeros [old new the-list]
  report map [[x] -> ifelse-value (x = old) [new] [x]] the-list
end
```

NetLogo 5 syntax:

```
to-report A-new-list-without-zeros [old new the-list]
  report map [ifelse-value (? = old) [new] [?]] the-list
end
```

Comment: Oh yea! I don't think I've ever used `ifelse-value` but this is great. Thanks @SethTisue!